# Array of Integers not changing values after parsing integer value from String

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a program where I am inputting the number of cows that I am going to input on the first line. Then I am inputting the cow name, a space, and then a 
   number (ie:Bessie 4) on each successive line, where I am using a delimiter to parse the string into 
   the name and the number, then putting it into an array. After that, if the 
   first cow name is Bessie, then I am adding the associated number value to 
   the first position of another array, called amountOfMilk, thereby changing 
   the array value. But when I input Bessie 4, Bessie 5, and Bessie 6 on three
   different lines the amountOfMilk array is [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] when it should be
   [15,0,0,0,0,0,0].

```
        int[] amountOfMilk = new int[7];
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfLogInputs = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLogInputs; i++) {
           String cowName = s.nextLine();
           String delimiter = "[ ]";
           String[] tokens = cowName.split(delimiter);
           if(tokens[0] == "Bessie") {
               amountOfMilk[0] += Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
           }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(amountOfMilk));
```

Comment: @khelwood is right. Change (tokens[0] == "Bessie) to ("Bessie".equals(tokens[0]))

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you so much.